# Undefined symbol in Scipy's lapack library

Tags: python, scipy

Today, I create a virtual environment in my server and also install the scipy package using pip install command.

But when I run my optimization function in server, there is a error showing that  **ImportError: /data/home/pxu/ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.so: undefined symbol: zlacn2_**

How can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the SciPy math dependencies via your OS package manager. On Ubuntu (and probably Debian) you can use

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev
```

Comment: Thank you. I use your code, but there is another error showing that the server couldn't find package libatlas-base-dev. I use **pip ** to install it, but my server could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement libatlas-base-dev.

Comment: It is an OS package, you do not install it with pip. What OS are you using?

Comment: Okay, great. But what Operating System is installed on your server? It looks like Linux, but what distribution is it? What do you see when you run `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: In my case I had both libraries installed already and what did the trick was simply to downgrade to a previous version of scipy (0.14.0). I'm on centos 5.9 and using python 2.7 under `pyenv`.